Download jar from a second maven repository
I have the following Gradle 8.9 configuration:
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.7'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '21'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.3")
    artifactory_contextUrl = "http://192.168.1.111/repository"
    external_artifactory_contextUrl = "http://12.22.31.201/repository"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-release"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
    maven {
        url "${external_artifactory_contextUrl}/plugins-release"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    ......
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

When I compile the project on Jenkins server I get error:

Could not get resource 'http://192.168.1.111/repository/plugins-release/com/....'.

The first repository is behind NAT. It should be switched to the second repository and jar should be download but for some reason it's not working. Do you know how I can fix this?

Feels like plugins-release is a mirror of Gradle Plugins portal, while you actually need to point your repositories {} at Maven Central mirror
